# How do I implement CloudPort side logic? JScript or VBScript produce an ActiveX control fault (even when left dummy, with empty-body functions)

Tags: vbscript, activex, jscript, single-threaded

The team I am working with has bought a CloudPort license (from CrossCheck Networks) and we are currently facing the problem of not being able to implement any sort of logic in the service Mocks (to control response selection). It would be something as simple as:

```
if (requestCounter++ == 1)
    then 
        response = $fn:Global(MyFirstXmlString)$ // <-- this is CloudP syntax for vrbls
    else 
        response = $fn:Global(MySecondXmlString)$.
```

We did not find any sample for using the Dll Plugin and neither of the two JScript and VBScript Tasks are working (i.e., our client machine gets back not the desired `MySecondXmlString` response but instead a Fault with

```
<faultstring>   
    ActiveX control '0e59f1d5-1fbe-11d0-8ff2-00a0d10038bc' cannot be instantiated 
    because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
</faultstring>.
```

Believe it or not, the fault above is being obtained even if the J- or VB-Script task is left empty! It's hard for us to believe that all the logic functionality advertised in the CloudPort UI is fake and that *nothing* is able to help one implement the kind of logic described above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Pompi

PS: A bit more details here on why the kind of logic described above is needed: We use SoapSonar in our testing framework to fire requests to a BizTalk orchestration application. The CP mocks are needed to simulate the environment of that BT orchestration. We cannot control individual mocked responses via SSonar requests: the (for cloudport: incoming) client requests are made by Production code and cannot be altered or controled by our SSonar client). The only Tasks functionality that worked for us is a DB-table working as an offline channel b/w SSonar and CP (SSonar writes in it and CP reads from it). CloudPort's reading of, say, responseXml's, from DB works fine but we cannot find a way to implement further behavior controlling logic on the CP side. Therefore, this stackoverflow posting. And thx for having the patience to read this whole shananigan :).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can control this from the script.

The threading model should be controlled by the host, which I suppose uses windows's "vbscript.dll" for the actual execution.
So if you cannot find any settings under the tool's options or in the help :), you should look in the registry keys for the threading options of that ActiveX or "vbscript.dll"
That is the "ThreadingModel" value and try to change the values (you will also have to search the net for those, don't know them by heart).

There are chances that some other application (antivirus?) has changes the path to the dll that the COM interface should actually point to (see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitpropriorver/thread/ac10bd5f-6d91-4aac-857c-0ed5758088ec)

Hope it helps.